# How to fix 'Chrome issue site not loading properly (Joomla)'

Tags: joomla

My website is on JOOMLA , It is loading fine in other browsers but not in CHROME .
The link of my website is . 
https://www.buildcorpinteriors.com

I have not tried anything but for searching for the solution which I may not be able to get .

https://www.buildcorpinteriors.com
This is the site link , If you open in chrome this website will not load properly but if load this website in other browser it works fine .
This website is on joomla

Comment: the image path that is showing in firebug is https://www.buildcorpinteriors.com/templates/yootheme/cache/Tribeca_Begelart_013_05.01.15_0000-68a1f082.webp which doesn't load an image.  Do you have issue when using a JPG/PNG as well?

Comment: mate I removed the cache and it took i guess some hours , the site is loading fine now .
I think it was cache issue